# how can I install a library with conda without affecting other libraries in Python

Tags: python, anaconda

I give the following example to illustrate my question.

I plan to install libpng 16 on my Ubuntu machine with the following command: `conda install libpng`. However, this will update the following packages:

```
    cairo:        1.12.18-3         --> 1.12.18-6         
    fontconfig:   2.11.1-3          --> 2.11.1-6          
    freetype:     2.5.2-1           --> 2.5.5-2           
    libgfortran:  1.0-0             --> 3.0.0-1           
    libpng:       1.5.13-1          --> 1.6.27-0          
    numpy:        1.8.2-py27_1      --> 1.11.3-py27_0     
    opencv:       2.4.9-np18py27_0  --> 3.1.0-np111py27_1 
    pixman:       0.26.2-0          --> 0.32.6-0          
    scikit-image: 0.9.3-np18py27_0  --> 0.13.0-np111py27_0
    scipy:        0.14.0-np18py27_0 --> 0.19.0-np111py27_0
```

I do not want to update these libraries for some reasons. May it be possible that libpng will be updated alone?

Comment: Use [virtualenv](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/how-to-use-python-virtualenv) if possible.

Comment: Do not use virtualenv with conda, use conda environments. virtualenv does not play very nicely with conda environments, and conda environments are built in.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do this, there is a `--no-update-dependencies` flag for the conda install command:

```
conda install --no-update-deps libpng
```

Beware that things might break though. More here: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html

A similar flag is available for the `conda update` flag as well, in case you're only updating a package, not installing it new.

Answer (score 1):

best approach might be:

- dry run install to see which dependencies conda would update
- install the new package while pinning versions of those dependencies to their current versions

i don't know a one-liner for this, but it would at least give you the behavior you want

Answer (score -1):

I think the

```py
--no-deps
```

flag is what you are looking for.

Comment: this does something quite different - avoiding new dependencies, not avoiding changes to already installed ones.